# How to update my apk every time I make changes on my template or code changes?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic4

How to update my apk every time I make changes on my template or code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `livereload` feature of `ionic cordova emulate` or `ionic cordova run` to run the code on an emulator or device and see the changes live as as you code.

Here's how with the emulator:

- `ionic cordova emulate android --list` to get a list of available emulator targets to copy into the next command.
- `ionic cordova emulate --livereload android -- --target="[TARGET]"`

See the CLI [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-emulate/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do livereload from a `ionic cordova run <platform>`, if it's an apk i assume that is for android so you can do this:

> ionic cordova run android --livereload

For more options like specific port you can take a look on the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run/)